# Unable to store proper date in NSDate

Tags: timezone, nsdate, ios9, nstimezone

I am trying to store dates in NSDate but not getting proper output.
Writing the code snippet below.

```
NSDate *firstDate = [NSDate dateWithYear:2015 month:12 day:1 ];
```

Expecting the output to be 2015-12-1 18:30:00 +0000.

But getting 2015-11-30 18:30:00 +0000

Ignore the time stamp.

dateWithYear:month:day is a category method which is there in the 3rd party calendar which I am using.the code of the method is as follows:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day {

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [NSDate componentsWithYear:year month:month day:day];



return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

}

```
return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

is

```
+ (NSDateComponents *)componentsWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day {

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:year];
[components setMonth:month];
[components setDay:day];

return components;
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would expect it to be 6.30pm UTC? And how are you getting the *output* at all? I suspect it's just creating a date at midnight in your local time zone. If that time zone is at UTC+05:30, then that would explain your output.

Comment: Jon ignore the time .How to get the exact date which i an giving as input .Do I need to set the time Zone?

Comment: "Ignore the time" makes no sense - it's part of the value, effectively. An `NSDate` is just an instant in time, and the code you have specified represents the instant in time which is midnight in your current time zone on the date specified. What exact instant in time do you *want* it to represent? (And where is `dateWithYear` specified? I can't see it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/)...)

Comment: The real question is, what is this method `dateWithYear:month:day` that you're using? That's not a standard `NSDate` method. It also doesn't exist on `NSCalendar`, which has convenience methods for creating dates from component values. Without seeing this method's code, it's impossible to say what it's going to return.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to set a date from data,

NSDateFormatter :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-12-01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

NSDateComponents : (you can add setSecond, setMinute, setHour for a specific time)

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setYear:2015];
[dateComps setMonth:12];
[dateComps setDay:1];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

Comment: Yes but are the results different from what the question describes?

Comment: @TomHarrington Isn't the question about how to set NSDate ?

Comment: Yes but if your code produces the same results as in the question, it's not an answer. Will your results be different?

Comment: Well I don't see any other way of doing this ... I've tested them when I submitted my answer and they worked fine